# Validate date in Oracle without using function

Tags: sql, oracle

I am newbie in Oracle. I have to select invalid dates in column in table in oracle database. But I also can't write function because of having read only rights in database.
Can anybody help to write simple query to select invalid date in columns:

e.g. select dates, to_date(dates 'yyyy/mm/dd')  from table

In the above query if the date is not in valid format it give error. But instead of error I have to output that date. Can we do it in simple query?

Answer (score 1):

You can test the format using a regular expression.

It would be something like:

```
select dates
from tbl
where regexp_like(dates, '[[:digit:]]{4}/[[:digit:]]{2}/[[:digit:]]{2}')
```

This works okay.  It checks that the format is in "4-digit number / 2 digit number / 2 digit number".  You might want something stronger, such as:

```
select dates
from tbl
where regexp_like(dates, '[[:digit:]]{4}/[[:digit:]]{2}/[[:digit:]]{2}') or
      (substr(dates, 1, 4) not between '1900' and '2014' or
       substr(dates, 6, 2) not between '01' and '12' 
       substr(dates, 9, 2) not between '01' and '31'
      )
```

This checks the format and for reasonable values in each column.  Of course, it doesn't check for June 31st, but it will catch many errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
select *
from tbl
where not regexp_like (dtstring,'^[[:digit:]{4},/,[:digit:]{2},/,[:digit:]{2}]')
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c7da3/11/0

Will show any values that are not 4 digits, followed by a slash, 2 more digits, followed by a slash, followed by 2 more digits.

It will not however check to see if a value matching that format is invalid, ie. 2012/23/99