# Orace SQL Case WHEN Statement "missing keyword"

Tags: sql

I am using BI Publisher with Oracle Fusion 19c

I am trying to look at a 1000 word VARCHAR field (POH.NOTE_TO_VENDOR), then if it contains the word Hearing and the character after it  (first part of the substr) are not blank ie a date exist. Then I want to convert the whole substr to a date other wise leave blank.

I can get the concatenated substr to work and display it as a string either as a date or if its not there then the value is '//' but cannot convert directly because if the value return '//' it wont convert this to date.

```
, CASE WHEN SUBSTR(POH.NOTE_TO_VENDOR, (INSTR(POH.NOTE_TO_VENDOR,'Hearing: ')+14),2)IS NOT NULL 
  THEN (TO_DATE((SUBSTR(POH.NOTE_TO_VENDOR, (INSTR(POH.NOTE_TO_VENDOR,'Hearing: ')+17),2)||'/'||SUBSTR(POH.NOTE_TO_VENDOR, (INSTR(POH.NOTE_TO_VENDOR,'Hearing: ')+14),2)||'/'||SUBSTR(POH.NOTE_TO_VENDOR, (INSTR(POH.NOTE_TO_VENDOR,'Hearing: ')+11),2)),'DD/MM/YY')) 
  ELSE 
  END
```

This code returns the error missing keyword. I want it to either convert the string to date or return a blank value.

Tried with an else condition without else and as it is

I have also tried Case when......then ‘1’ else ‘0’ which returns 1 and 0s correctly

Comment: You should put something after `ELSE`. For instance `NULL`. Just a wild guess though...

Comment: Tried that did not work still missing keyword

Comment: Or remove ELSE which eventually would result to NULL if WHEN fails.

Comment: Also tried with no else

Comment: Removing else still returns same error

Comment: update your question and show all the query code  ..

Comment: The query is fairly large and I think would add no value to the above, because without the to_date and the case when I am getting values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in this chaos of parentheses.
I removed all the unnecessary parentheses which make the code hard to read and hard to spot the syntactical errors:

```
, CASE WHEN SUBSTR(POH.NOTE_TO_VENDOR, INSTR(POH.NOTE_TO_VENDOR,'Hearing: ') + 14, 2) IS NOT NULL 
    THEN TO_DATE(
      SUBSTR(POH.NOTE_TO_VENDOR, INSTR(POH.NOTE_TO_VENDOR,'Hearing: ') + 17, 2)
      || '/' ||
      SUBSTR(POH.NOTE_TO_VENDOR, INSTR(POH.NOTE_TO_VENDOR,'Hearing: ') + 14, 2)
      || '/' ||
      SUBSTR(POH.NOTE_TO_VENDOR, INSTR(POH.NOTE_TO_VENDOR,'Hearing: ') + 11, 2),
      'DD/MM/YY'
    ) 
  END
```

I also removed `ELSE` which is not needed if you only need `NULL` in that case.

Comment: If i remove the to_date and case when it works but like i say its not a date value so cannot do days counts etc, plus I would like to get rid of the // when no date found. Thanks i will try your above

Comment: Chaos of the parentheses sounds like a movie titke

Comment: Don't overuse parentheses. Use them only when needed and don't surround every function with them. If you want to check the validity of the date returned by the concatenation you must do further checking before to_date()

Comment: Thats exactly what I am trying to do, tried to do a ISDate but could not get that to work, so started with a case when. Also regarding parentheses i do try not use them but when writing the code i always have the syranx for the logic i am trying to write and put any nested logic in brackets just to ensure my syntax is correct/workable, however this does make it hard to read. Admittedley I should then go back over the statement and try and cut out the parentheses

Comment: Essentially what the above is trying to achieve is if the concat is a value which can turned into a date then turn it into a date otherwise return null, then I can do date comparisons etc

Comment: Check these posts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45475877/check-string-of-characters-is-a-valid-date-or-not, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702050/valid-date-checks-in-oracle, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105049/validate-date-in-oracle-without-using-function

Comment: Thank you i cannot creat functions i dont think in our environment

Comment: Looked at the above posts i think your soloution is better for me i shall see when i am back in the office and see if it lets me convert to_date

Comment: My code is not about the validity and conversion of the text to date. It is about the syntactical error *missing keyword* you mention in your question. Still you have to validate that the returned string is a valid date.

Comment: I know that if the first 2 characters are not null then the concat can only be a date value, but i will also try and run some logic to also check that it is also a date